# Back up Thunderbird Calendars automatically

Tags: backup, thunderbird, automation, calendar, thunderbird-addon

I want to back up my Thunderbird calendars somehow, but I'm not sure how without manually going to "Events and Tasks", "Export" and then choosing each calendar one at a time. I have a lot of calendars and I update them daily, so this is really inconvenient. I want to keep nightly backups in case the computer's OS drive dies.

I see an appdata folder at

`C:\Users\username\AppData\Roaming\Thunderbird\Profiles\{profile_digits}.default-release\calendar-data`

which contains some .sqlite files, but I have no idea if simply making a backup of this folder will actually save my calendars.

I found an old add-on that looked as thouugh it could do it, but Thunderbird told me it was corrupted when I tried to install it:
https://addons.thunderbird.net/en-us/thunderbird/addon/automatic-export/

Is there any easy way to keep an automatic backup of my calendars in Thunderbird?

Comment: As long as Thunderbird is closed so that it completes any database operations and closes the .sqlite files, backing up the profile folder should work for you.

Answer (score 0):

There's an extension called **ImportExportTools NG**.

https://addons.thunderbird.net/en-US/thunderbird/addon/importexporttools-ng/

It allows you to back up your entire profile, which in essence will include all configured tasks and calendars. It also has an option to schedule backups automatically.

I was able to install and run it in current ***Thunderbird*** (*v.115.6.1*).

Comment: Thanks for sharing, but for some reason it doesn't appear to be backing anything up. I set these settings, but the folder I told it to back up to daily is still empty, after over 2 days (48 hours):
https://i.imgur.com/ltJlBL6.png
Any idea why it isn't making backups of the profile?

Comment: I can only guess, but since it's an Extension, Thunderbird probably needs to be open when the backup runs. You can check that.

Comment: Another thing, reviewing your screenshot, is that you are trying to save the backup to a network route. Perhaps it's having trouble doing that. Have you been able to test if it does the backup locally first?